# "gnosis-safe" I need help in DID method creation

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm Shahzad Ali, Actually I'm here to know how to make new DID method and DID registry.Can you please help me in this.
I'm Student and want to explore how to create DID document, registry and ,method. Please help me.

Comment: Please provide more information about DID

Comment: Actually my main concern is that i want to create DID registry on Ethereum by using IPFS and then i want to create DID method. so my supervisor can generate the DIDs by using my DID method.

Comment: Please help me my dear.

Comment: This question is too broad. For code questions, you must first try something and if you encounter a specific problem, then ask here. This stack is not meant to work for you.

Comment: why is it tages as gnosis-safe?  check this https://github.com/uport-project/ethr-did  https://veramo.io/docs/veramo_agent/did_methods/#:~:text=Ethr%2DDID%20provides%20a%20scalable,smart%20contract%20based%20identity%20methods.  https://developer.uport.me/ethr-did/docs/index